# Can a sequence of finitely many elementary operations/algorithm give a specific closed form for a recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> $$\color{blue}{\textbf{Tldr : How to prove the following algorithmically without induction?}}$$
>
> $$\color{red} {a_{n} = 1 + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\right) a_{n-1} \implies a_{n} = \sum _{r=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\binom{n}{r}}}  $$

Consider the sequence

$$ a_{n} = \sum _{r=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\binom{n}{r}} \tag{*}$$

I proved [here (Lemma 1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238873/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-fracn12n1-left-fract1/1239007#1239007) that it satisfies the recurrence relation $$a_{n} = 1 + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\right) a_{n-1} \tag{$\dagger$}$$

Now, we can solve this recurrence relation by forming telescopic sums by a sequence of finitely many elementary operations (addition, multiplication, compositions of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) etc.), to obtain an alternative closed form.

In particular,

$$\dfrac{2^n}{n+1}a_n - a_1 = \sum_{r=2}^{n} \left(\dfrac{2^r}{r+1} a_{r} - \dfrac{2^{r-1}}{r} a_{r-1} \right) = 
\sum_{r=2}^{n} \dfrac{2^r}{r+1}$$

Which, after simplifying, gives the elegant identity,

$$ a_n = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\binom{n}{r}} = \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\right) \sum_{r=1}^{n+1} \dfrac{2^r}{r} $$

> **Question : Is it possible to recover the original closed form $(*)$, without prior knowledge of it and just from the recurrence $(\dagger)$ and some initial values, by using a sequence of finitely many elementary operations (similar to what was done for the other closed form obtained here)?**

**Elaborating on what I'm looking for :**

- I'm looking for an algorithm to get $(*)$ from $(\dagger)$, involving finite combinatorial methods (elementary operations, binomial transforms etc.), so Integrals are excluded.
- I wrote "without prior knowledge" to avoid the use of [ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz). Methods based on induction assume prior knowledge and are excluded.

**I'm seeking an algorithm so that it can be generalized to a large class of recurrence relations.**

Comment: Are you willing to consider using a generating function approach? E.g. $G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$.

Comment: @Alex R. I'd prefer a finite method, but you can post it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, but is too long for a comment. Below is a natural, ansatz-free method that surprisingly leads to the double of the wished result. I suspect that with a little more ingenuity, it can lead to a full solution.

So, we start with the recurrence relation

$$
a_n=1 + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\right) a_{n-1} \tag{$A_0$}
$$

Step 1 : we are optimistic, and assume that $(a_n)$ has a limit, in other words that there has an expansion of the form $a_n=l+o(1)$. Passing to the limit in $(A_0)$ above, we see that $l=2$. This suggests the rescaling $a_n=2+b_n$, which yields

$$
b_n=\dfrac{1}{n} + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\right) b_{n-1} \tag{$B_0$}
$$

Step 2 : we are optimistic, and assume that $(a_n)$ has a Taylor expansion of the form $a_n=2+\dfrac{l}{n}+o(\dfrac{1}{n})$. Then $l$ is the limit of the sequence $a_n^1=nb_n$, so let us see what recurrence relation is satisfied by this new sequence. It turns out to be

$$
a^1_n=1 + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2(n-1)}\right)a^1_{n-1} \tag{$A_1$}
$$

Step $3$: Passing to the limit in $(A_1)$ above, we see that the limit of $a^1_n$ is $2$ if it exists. This suggests the rescaling $a^1_n=2+b^1_n$, which yields

$$
b^1_n=\dfrac{2}{n-1} + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2(n-1)}\right) b^1_{n-1} \tag{$B_1$}
$$

Step 4: arguing as in step 2, let us now put $a_n^2=(n-1)b^1_n$ (we use $n-1$ rather than $n$, because of the $n-1$ in the denominator of $(B_1)$ above). We deduce

$$
a^2_n=2 + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2(n-2)}\right)a^1_{n-1} \tag{$A_2$}
$$

Iterating this argument, we obtain for every $k\geq 0$,

$$
\begin{array}{lclc}
a^k_n &=& k! + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2(n-k)}\right)a^k_{n-1} & (A_k) \\
b^k_n &=& \dfrac{(k+1)!}{2(n-k)} + \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2(n-k)}\right)b^k_{n-1} & (B_k)
\end{array}
$$

and we have the successive identities

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
a_n &=& 2+ \dfrac{1}{n}a^1_n \\
    &=& 2+ \dfrac{2}{n} +\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}a^2_n \\
    &=& 2+ \dfrac{2}{n} +\dfrac{4}{n(n-1)} +\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)}a^3_n \\
    &=& \ldots \\
\end{array}
$$

At the $r$-th step ($0\leq r \lt n $) of this iteration, we obtain

$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{r}\dfrac{2k!}{n(n-1)\ldots(n-(k-1))}
         + \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-r)}a^r_n 
$$

In other words,

$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{r}\dfrac{2}{\binom{n}{k}}
         + \dfrac{(r+1)!}{\binom{n}{r+1}}a^r_n \tag{1}
$$

In particular, when $r=n-1$,

$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{2}{\binom{n}{k}}
         + n!a^{n-1} _n \tag{2}
$$

Comment: (+1) Seems promising! I'll look into it in detail tomorrow since it is quite late here.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain his or her reasons ?